# QGIS 3.16.16 OGR error Coordinates

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates, error

I am editing shapefiles that are derived from data measured with a GPS. I have made several adjustments without problems. Suddenly when I want to add a point to a feature or want to add a new feature and save these changes, I get the following error: *''Coordinates with non-finite values are not allowed.''*

Nevetheless I can change the locations of original points and save these changes.
This problem is also occuring in the original shapefiles.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which CRS are you working with?

Comment: @Erik with CRS is 28992 Amersfoort/RD New

Comment: did you reproject the original data to 28992? If so, how you did it? You must remember that gps data come in epsg 4326, so in order to be in 28992 you must properly reproject your data...

Comment: @Gerardo Jimenez We use the program SurfCE for our GPS. When we export to .shp it automaticaly reprojects it to 28992. So when we import our .shp into QGis it's already in the CRS we need. For this project this went fine, just like normal. Its only later on that the problem occured. It also doesn't happen with all layers. We just added a new feature to one of the layers that didn't have the issue. We could save it, but then when we add more points to that feature, it won't let us save anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out the error occurs when we export the shapefiles with the M-value data, but the point doesn't have a M-value. If we export them without, it doesn't give us any trouble.

Edit: You can also edit the M-value afterwards in Q-Gis. Use the ''point editor'' tool to manually give the 'nan' values in the the M-value column a number value, for instance 0.

Comment: What is an "M-value"?

Comment: The M-value is a value that relates to the 3D/4D space. We think it's the depth of a point. We've found that if you set a layer in edit mode and then use the ''edit points/point editor tool'' you can manually set the M-value shown in the points-table to NULL. Then Q-Gis has no problem with it anymore.